# IONIC 3 IOS : bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 13.5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, wkwebview

my application is rejected by apple team : i have a problem on ipad 13.5.1.
the probelme is that I can’t specify IOS 13.5.1 on the simulator target : only version 13.5 is allowed.

I note that I fixed the problems on version 13.5 caused by wkwebview.

[image]

Comment: can somebody help me?

Comment: I am also running into this issue loaded the app on an ipad running 13.5.1 myself and it worked fine but apple rejected the binary twice now saying there was a white screen would love to hear from the ionic team what they are doing to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assalemu Alaikom.

Try to download the last beta version of Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more
It will install ios 13.6
And you can try iPad simulator.

Comment: How to get iOS 13.5.1 simulator? Its not even present in Xcode 12 BETA.